# how to check if the pdf file is portfolio pdf & extract a attached file from portfolio pdf in xamarin forms

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, portfolio

In my project I have a requirement to get the portfolio pdf & display it in WebView or inside App. Is there a way to check if the pdf file is portfolio pdf & extract a attached file from portfolio pdf in xamarin forms without using any 3rd party licensed package.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is a "portfolio pdf"?

Comment: @Jason 
A PDF Package/Portfolio is when multiple documents are packaged together into one PDF file. The documents can be in different formats and created in different applications.

Comment: OK but what technically differentiates that from a "standard" PDF?  Is "portfolio" actually defined in the PDF spec?  Or is it just a common usage pattern?

Comment: @Jason a PDF portfolio is a standard PDF file with document level attachments. It has a couple of additional properties that let you know that it is a portfolio, meaning the attachments are the important content and not the actual PDF file which might contain just a blank PDF page. In a portfolio the PDF file serves merely as a container for the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee you can detect a type of PDF content before decompression by a third party app UNLESS the text wrapper contains an easy to detect mix of /Tags.

The classic Adobe sample varies over time but a current X sample at https://community.adobe.com/havfw69955/attachments/havfw69955/acrobat/256250/1/Sample%20Portfolio.pdf

Shows this (partial text view)

```
<</AcroForm 244 0 R/Collection 156 0 R/Lang(en)/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 58 0 R/Names 153 0 R/PageMode/UseAttachments/Pages 81 0 R/StructTreeRoot 62 0 R/Type/Catalog/
```

The key point to note is the combination of "`/Type/Catalog/`" with "`/Collection`"

A bigger, much older version 9, is at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/marketing-hub/pdfs/Portfolio_Asset_Publisher_Training_Resources.pdf

So let's see if it can be parsed easily.

This is not a really good "Regex" pattern using Windows native search, but it shows the method working:

[image]

```
findstr /R "\/Type.*\/Catalog \/Collection" Portfolio.PDF
```